# How to make sure the user just logged in?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a web  control panel with links to sensitive informations (like credit card number). 
When the user clicks (who got logged in before) on one of these link, I need to check his credntials.

How can I make sure on the server side when he requests ("/sensitive-informations.aspx") that he just entered his credentials ?

EDIT : the main problem here is the "he just entered his credentials" , I need to make sure that he comes DIRECTLY from the login page.

Comment: what are you using for authenticate the user? You can call a service or http-handler on link click and check for the credential of the current user.

Comment: @krshekhar the problem here is not how to log the user in, but is how do I know that he just (the previous page) entered his credentials

Comment: @remobourgarel why don't you send these value from previous page. and check on page load

Comment: which values ? which page load ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. For instance, after the user enters his credentials, save them in the [Session object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Then, in the `Page_Load` of *sensitive-informations.aspx* make sure the Session object exists.

To better illustrate this:

In your login.aspx.cs page:

```
protected btnLoginClick(...)
{
   // CHECK USERNAME and PASSWORD
   if (UserIsAuthenticated)
   {
      Session["UserName"] = user;
   }
}
```

Then in your sensitive-informations.aspx.cs

```
protected page_load(...)
{
    // If UserName doesn't exist in Session, don't allow access to page
    if (Session["UserName"] == null)
    {
       Response.Redirect("INVALID_USER.aspx");
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Based on OPs comments, if you want to know *which page* you came from, you can either use:
[**Page.PreviousPage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = this.Page.PreviousPage;
```

Or use [**Request.UrlReferrer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = Request.UrlReferrer;
```

In both cases make sure `x` isn't null first...

Comment: I know how to restrict access to a page, but what I need to make sure is that the user comes directly from the login page.

Comment: as I said to Andy , we first though about this solution but some antivirus software take off the referer and we can'thave a few user (even 0.1%) unable to see this page.

Comment: @remibourgarel If you use `Server.Transfer` after he enters the credentials, you will always have the Page.PreviousPage

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I have to change the behavior of my login page and I can't change my login page "Response.Redirect(originUrl)" because that'll put my whole system  under the "/login.aspx" url (Server.Transfer happens on the server side, not the browser)

Comment: Either you're not explaining yourself clearly or you're not sure *what* you want exactly... You yourself said that any Response.Redirect / href link etc. will *not work* due to some Antivirus program running. So you don't really have any other choice but to use `Server.Transfer` since you're saying you can't use anything which is based on the client side... The only other tip I can give you is to store in the Session *which page the user last requested* and then you can know from where he came to that page...

Comment: Response.Redirect is not the problem, the problem with your solution is trusting the referer

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `UrlReferrer` in the `Page_Load` event of `sensitive-informations.aspx`:

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
     if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("you-login-page"))
     {
        //User came from the login page
     }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Based on your comment, you should check the `LastLoginDate` property of the [MembershipUser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za59c2aa.aspx)

This will give you the, well, last login date of the current user. You can compare that with the current date/time to make sure that the user "just entered their credentials". Couple this with the checking where the user came from (either with `Request.UrlReferrer` or `Page.PreviousPage`).

Comment: We first though it but some antivirus software take off the referer and we can'thave a few user (even 0.1%) unable to see this page.